# Material UI DesktopDatePicker SX styling

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, styling

I'm currently trying to modify the `DesktopDatePicker` component from `@materialui` so far here is my code.

```
import { DesktopDatePicker } from '@mui/x-date-pickers/DesktopDatePicker';
import { LocalizationProvider } from '@mui/x-date-pickers/LocalizationProvider/LocalizationProvider';
import { AdapterDayjs } from '@mui/x-date-pickers/AdapterDayjs';
import dayjs from 'dayjs'
import TextField from '@mui/material/TextField';
import { makeStyles } from '@mui/material/styles';

function App() {
    <li className='form-calendar'>
        {/* <input type='text' placeholder="Birthdate"
            value={data.birth_date} 
            onChange={(event) => setdata({ ...data, birth_date: event.target.value })
        } /> */}  
        <LocalizationProvider dateAdapter={AdapterDayjs} > 
            <DesktopDatePicker className = "{classes.root}"
                label="Birthday"
                value={data.birth_dates}
                minDate={dayjs('2017-01-01')}
                onChange={(event) => {setdata({ ...data, birth_dates: event.target.value })}}
                renderInput={(params) => 
                    <TextField {...params} 
                        sx={{
                            width:200,
                            marginTop: 2,
                            marginBottom:2,
                            borderStyle: "10px dotted",
                            "& .MuiPaper-root": {
                                backgroundColor: "rgba(120, 120, 120, 0.2)"
                            },
                            "& .MuiInputBase-root": {
                                borderStyle: "10px dotted rgba(45, 85, 255, 0.4)"
                            },
                            "& .MuiFormLabel-root": {
                                color: "rgb(229,228,226)",
                            },
                            "&. MuiInputBase-input.MuiOutlinedInput-input": { 
                                color: "rgba(120, 120, 120, 0.4)" 
                            }                   
                        }}
                    />
                }
            />
        </LocalizationProvider>
    </li>
}
```

I've managed to change the `MuiFormLabel-root` using the `sx` props but am struggling modify the `border` and `font color` for the component. Any help would be greatly appreciated.
[image]

I've tried using the `makeStyles` to customize the color but still haven't succeeded.

Answer (score 0):

Try to add this style to your TextField sx props:

```js
sx={{
    '& label': {
        color: 'white'
    },
    '& label.Mui-focused': {
        color: 'white',
    },
    '& .MuiInput-underline:after': {
        borderBottomColor: 'white',
    },
    '& .MuiOutlinedInput-root': {
        color: 'white',
        '& fieldset': {
            borderColor: 'white',
        },
        '&:hover fieldset': {
            borderColor: 'white',
        },
        '&.Mui-focused fieldset': {
            borderColor: 'white',
        },
    }
}}
```

Comment: Please accept the answer if it meets your solution.